# Passing in a date to WebAPI - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a GET request that I make in Chrome Postman. It looks like the following:

> http://localhost/WCAPI/Lookup/WCClassDesc/State/AL/Class/7230/DescCode/00/EffDate/2016-04-13

Can anybody see why I would get this response in Postman?

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/WCAPI/Lookup/WCClassDesc/State/AL/Class/7230/DescCode/00/EffDate/2016-04-13'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'WCClassDesc' that matches the request."
}
```

My code is:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.Http;
    /// <summary>
    /// API for loading WCClassDescription which is shown on the PremByClass page. 


    namespace WCAPI.Controllers.Lookup {

        [RoutePrefix("Lookup/WCClassDesc")]
        public class WCClassDescController : ApiController {

            [Route("State/{State}/Class/{Class}/DescCode/{DescCode}/EffDate/{EffDate}")]
            public Models.Lookup.WCClassDesc Get(string ClassState, string ClassCode, string DescCode, DateTime EffDate) {

                var desc = (new Premium.BLL.WCClassDesc()).GetCurrentWCClassDesc(ClassState, ClassCode, DescCode, EffDate);
                var WC = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Models.Lookup.WCClassDesc>(desc);
                return WC;

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code, let's start from the URI:

Assuming you are testing your application using the root path of your host (localhost) and following your definition of `RoutePrefix` and `Route` attributes, the correct URI for your resource is the following:

```
http://localhost/Lookup/WCClassDesc/State/AL/Class/7230/DescCode/00/EffDate/2016-04-13
```

That's because there is no `WCAPI` defined in your `RoutePrefix` attribute.

The other problem is related to the route parameter mapping, you defined you parameters as `{State}` and `{Class}`, but then you are asking for `ClassState` and `ClassCode` inside your method.

Rename those parameters to match the ones defined in your route, or else Web API will not map them to your method parameters.